# How to say "I speak Japanese but it's not my first language" in Japanese

Tags: grammar

I'm self-learning Japanese, and I usually struggle with the grammar. Because English is my first language, I was wondering how you would say "I speak Japanese but it's not my first language". Does 日本語を話せます、でも私の第一言語ありません sound correct?

Comment: Do you know the difference between ありません and ではありません? 私の第一言語ありません sounds like "my  first language doesn't exist".

Answer (score 4):

I would use [母(国)語]{ぼ・こく・ご} ("native language").  Sounds more natural.

> 日本語が話せますけど、母(国)語ではありません

Comment: This is a valid answer. However, I, a picky nerd, would prefer to distinguish  母語 (one's mother tongue) from 母国語 (the language of one's nation) and annoyingly insist that the former should be used here. See: http://user.keio.ac.jp/~rhotta/hellog/2016-12-30-1.html . Though literally no one around me cares.

Comment: @Yoshi this is interesting because it deals with the assumption that one's own mother tongue is the same than one's nation language, which might not be necessarily true for areas where multiple languages are spoken